# How to view a hierarchy of all components in react dev tools?

Tags: reactjs, react-devtools

Asking this because it is gets a bit hard to inspect them manually one by one in react dev tools (e.g. openning up the App component and travers all the way down manually is a bit cumbersome when viewing sample codes). It would be helpful if I could see a simple hierarchy of all the components in a project.

Comment: you're right, this would be great. parsing / inspecting tree structures is an entire discipline within computer science on its own, particularly when the structures are dynamic / cyclical. I don't think there's a simple solution but I'm certain something will eventually emerge. It would be great if you could amend your question with a sketch of what you're expecting to see

Comment: Thanks @azium for the comment, sure I will amend a sketch to it.